# Reset not all search fields when you click button 'Reset'

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

By default, when you press the **button** 'Reset', all search filters fields are reset, but I need to leave one of the fields with the previous value after reset. I can not understand how to save the **previous value** in one of the search fields after click button 'Reset' **(page reloads after clicking button 'Reset')**.

Tell me, please, ideas for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery.

```
<script>
    $('#resetButtonId').click(function(){
        var fieldId= $('#fieldid').val();
        //Your code to reset field value

        // Add this line to set value for particular field
        $('#fieldid').val(fieldId);``
   });
</script>
```